# ubuntu 18 не работают некоторые клавиши на клавиатуре

Tags: ubuntu

Поставил ubuntu 18 на ноутбук, на клавиатуре которая подключена к ноутбуку не работают клавиши super, l ctrl , l alt , r ctrl, r alt, при этом на самом ноуте эти клавиши работают, при включенной экранной клавиатуре при нажатии не работающих клавиш на подключенной клавиатуре отображается что нажал на левый шифт. В чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, неполадка вызвана некорректным определением модели Вашей клавиатуры.

Для исправления данной проблемы перейдите в **Настройки**->**Оборудование**->**Клавиатура**->**Раскладка**. Там можно будет выбрать модель клавиатуры.

Comment: Выбор клавиатуры не нашел , но наталкнули на мысль о поиске проблемы с подключением клавиатуры , у меня игровая клава  red dragon , нашел статью там описываються проблемы с ней. Вот ссылка если что http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=294145.0